# How to use cloud stack API Using java / python?

Tags: java, python, stack, cloud, apache-cloudstack

Is there any way to use cloud stack API along with java / python?

In the clouds stack documents they only provided the information about the interface of the API.  how to use those API along with programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudStack API’s can be accessed using

**Using Command Line Interface (CLI) CloudMonkey** - https://cwiki.apache.org/CLOUDSTACK/cloudstack-cloudmonkey-cli.html

**Using Https Requests** - http://cloudstack.apache.org/docs/en-US/Apache_CloudStack/4.0.0-incubating/html-single/API_Developers_Guide/

**Using CloudStack Clients** - https://github.com/jasonhancock/cloudstack-python-client

We can make two types of Http requests

1. Unauthenticated API Requests using port 8096 (open port 8096 using management UI)
2. Authenticated API Requests using signature

**Sample Python code to create Signature**

```
import urllib2
import urllib // to make the url request 
import hashlib              //encode it to http
import hmac
import base64      //encording 

request={}
request['command']='listUsers'
request['response']='xml'
request['apikey']='zdfhgsdhfgseahyg'
secretkey='ghfgfgfg'

>>> request
{'apikey': 'plgWJfZK4gyS3mOMTVmjUVg-X-jlWlnfaUJ9GAbBbf9EdM-kAYMmAiLqzzq1ElZLYq_u38zCm0bewzGUdP66mg', 'command': 'listUsers', 'response': 'json'}

>>>request_url="&".join(["=".join([r,urllib.quote_plus(request[r])]) for r in request.keys()])

>>>sig_url="&".join(["=".join([r.lower(),urllib.quote_plus(request[r]).lower()]) for r in sorted(request.iterkeys())])

>>>sig=urllib.quote_plus(base64.encodestring(hmac.new(secretkey,sig_url,hashlib.sha1).digest()).strip())

>>> req=url+request_url+'&signature='+sig
>>> res=urllib2.urlopen(req)
>>> res.read()
```

Comment: Hi nikhil Can u answer this question of mine?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877953/calling-cloud-stack-with-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Probably this [example](https://github.com/jasonhancock/cloudstack-python-client/blob/master/example1.py) can help you,

Also have a look at their [api](http://download.cloud.com/releases/3.0.0/api_3.0.0/TOC_Root_Admin.html) ,

The [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/First+Steps+with+Cloudstack+using+DevCloud) page is also a good one to start working with the api.

Comment: Hi Ruben Can you Please answer this question of mine
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877953/calling-cloud-stack-with-parameters